# How to run the plugin in cefsharp?

Tags: plugins, command-line, cefsharp

I have WinForms application with CEF. I create my oun plugin and I want to run it in CEF. But in no running.

My goal is to run my plugin. In work with Chrome good.
My InitializeChromium() is:

```
public void InitializeChromium()
{
     string pluginPath = @"C:\Users\....AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\iifchhfnnmpdbibifmljnfjhpififfog /Run=yes";
     CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
     CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
     settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("single-process", "1");
     settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("plugin-launcher", pluginPath);
     Cef.Initialize(settings);
     _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
     this.Controls.Add(_browser);
     _browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

I expect the plugin's work. How to run my plugin?

Comment: Looks like you mean extension rather than plugin.  CEF only has limited extension support, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2497 for details.  Also single process is only for debugging purposes,  not supported in production use, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I meant exactly the plugin, which, when you launch the "www.google.com" page, searches the history of visits and loads pages that have been visited more than 3 times in the last week, and also launches the C # application, which registers these pages in the database. There is simply no idea how I can run my plugin.

Comment: Only limited support for extension currently exist. You cannot load your plugin because plugins aren't supported.